# YAWL resourceService deployment on websphere

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-8

Has anyone yet deployed YAWL resourceService on Websphere 7 or 8. We are trying to do the same, but it gives JSF error after entering the credentials. It seems the IBM websphere implementation for JSF is not compatible with the one used by resourceService. Can someone throw light on how to force WebSphere to use JSF implementation bundled within the application itself and not to use its own.
Here is the exception stack trace, I am getting.

```
[9/24/12 15:56:05:138 IST] 00000015 lifecycle     E   JSF1054: (Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1, View ID: "") Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@3b803b8]
[9/24/12 15:56:05:143 IST] 00000015 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet Faces Servlet in application resourceService_war. Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException: Array index out of range: 4
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.sun.rave.web.ui.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.yawlfoundation.yawl.resourcing.jsf.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.yawlfoundation.yawl.util.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:52)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 4
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1167)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1171)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:334)
    at com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Please provide the error log that is genereated. Also, websphere 7 or 8, which one?

Comment: I am using websphere 7. But we will have to port it to 8 as well.

Comment: Provide error log that you get. Also provide details, which jsf does your application uses? The version ?  Fyi was7 ships with myfaces1.2 and was8 with jsf2.0 .. Please update question with asked details so can help.you better

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have the details with me right now. I will get it once I will join my office. You can try for YAWL 2.2, which comes along with resourceService. That might provide answer to your questions.

Comment: Update the question when you get back to office after weekend, and leave a comment tagging me so that I know you updated it.

Answer (score 0):

websphere by default provides JSF1.2 implementation.

In the case described, you can configure your application to use the version of JSF provided inside the application.

I guess [THIS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tweb_jsf.html) is what you are looking for.

Please follow the instructions in the above document to configure your server to take jsf from application.

Comment: Stack Trace : 00000015 lifecycle E JSF1054: (Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1, View ID: "") Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@3b803b8] 00000015 servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet Faces Servlet in application resourceService_war. Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException: Array index out of range: 4 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)...

Comment: @CuriousMind please post complete stack trace. and update the question with it. dont post in comment. its difficult to read from comment

Answer (score 0):

Curious mind, 
  Please try changing the state saving mode to client side by changing the attribute in web.xml (STATE_SAVING_METHOD).

Comment: Were you able to get rid of the exception?

Comment: No luck, it still failed. :(

Comment: No we are still struggling with it. Unfortunately we had to take decision that YAWL ui won't be available only its services can be accessed.